# R convert list to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
A<-c("a","b","c","d")
B<-c("a","b","c","d")
C<-list(c("a","b","c","d"),c("a","b","c","d"))
D<-c("a","b","c","d")

x<-list(A,B,C,D)
```

How to convert list x to data frame without using "for" ?

Comment: Have u tried `data.frame(x)` and change the column names

Comment: What does your desired data frame look like? Is each element in the list to be converted into a column? A row? A list within a cell?

Answer (score 1):

A data frame needs to have columns of the same length. Your C column has only two elements since it is composed of two lists with four items in each list, I assume C is meant to be a 2 column 4 row data frame. name the list elements for better column names in the final data frame.

```
A<-c("a","b","c","d")
B<-c("a","b","c","d")    
C<-list(C1 = c("a","b","c","d"), C2= c("a","b","c","d"))
D<-c("a","b","c","d")
df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
```